# Removing an object loaded with OBJLoader Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

This may seem like a very trivial problem but I can't find a solution to this. I've added an object to the scene using OBJLoader as seen below. How can I remove it from the scene? I've tried using code to clear scene.children, but this doesn't remove my "flower.obj"

```
        const mloader = new THREE.OBJLoader();        
        
        mloader.load
        (
            'models/flower.obj', function(object)
            {
                object.scale.x=1
                object.translateZ(2);
                scene.add(object);
            }
        );
```

Comment: You might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-cleanup.html)  useful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to save a reference to the loaded object so you can subsequently call [`scene.remove()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.remove) when you're ready to get rid of it.

```js
var flower;
const mloader = new THREE.OBJLoader();        
        
mloader.load('models/flower.obj',
    function(object) {
        flower = object;
        flower.scale.x=1
        flower.translateZ(2);
        scene.add(flower);
    }
);

function removeFlower() {
    scene.remove(flower);
}
```

Comment: So I've tried copying this exactly and the flower still remains in the scene after calling the removeFlower function.

Comment: When are you calling `removeFlower()`? Make sure it gets called after the `.obj` file has finished loading, otherwise it won't do anything.

Comment: I am calling further down in the code, in multiple different locations and it's still there. Really don't know how to get rid of this immortal flower.